# Confusion matrix from two shapefile fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, confusion-matrix

I have a shapefile with two columns one with `joinreal` and `predicted` values. I would like to calculate the confusion matrix between these two columns.

I tried something in PyQGIS, but it does not work

```
# Get the layer containing the two columns
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('E:/33-area_urbana/GEO2/seg_s10_r3_m10_fix_estat/validacao.shp')[0]

# Create the confusion matrix
confusion_matrix = QgsConfusionMatrix(layer, 'predicted', 'joinreal')

# Get the results of the confusion matrix
result = confusion_matrix.calculate()
```

source file: https://github.com/wesleysc352/wesleysc352.github.io/blob/master/validation.zip

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in
> runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)    File "", line 1, in     File "", line 2, in  IndexError: list index out of
> range

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you getting an error message, unexpected results or something else?

Comment: @firefly-orange i updated the question